# IObservable.Add vs. IObservable.Subscribe

Tags: f#, system.reactive, reactive-programming, observable, subscribe

What is the difference between these two methods, and what is the best situation for each? I know they are both able to attach a function for handling emissions from an IObservable, but I don't really understand the differences beyond that.

EDIT

Sorry, I should have specified. The definition of IObservable.Add is here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370414.aspx

Maybe it's just an F# thing. I'm using F# by the way. Not C#.

Comment: What's that `Add`-method, where is it defined ?

Comment: I'd wager that `Subscribe` lets you unsubscribe while `Add` doesn't, so `Add` is only useful if you'd `ignore` the result of `Subscribe` anyway.

Comment: @ildjarn indeed it is in the description: **Permanently** connects a listener function to the observabl

Answer (score 2):

Appreciating I'm a bit late to the party...

In the context of `FSharp.Control.Observable`:

- `add` does indeed subscribe to the observable, returning `unit`.
- `subscribe` is as above, but instead returns an `IDisposable` that can be used to **un**subscribe.

Source: [From `FSharp.Core` documentation](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-control-observablemodule.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is no extension method `IObservable.Add` in the Rx library, and this method is not part of the interface - so I am not sure where you got that from. `IObservable.Subscribe` is the means by which an observer subscribes for notifications from an Observable stream.

You can see the full definitions of these interfaces (which are part of the .NET Base Class Library from version 4.0) here:

- [`IObservable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`IObserver`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783449(v=vs.110).aspx)

You may wish to look at the resources for Rx on the msdn page [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx) - especially the videos, since it appears you are at the start of your Rx journey.

#### Edit

In light of the clarification that you are using F# - yes it appears `Add` is F# specific, as well as the `Subscribe` extension method you are referring too; I've never used it in C#. Both these F# methods appear to only react to `OnNext` notifications and as such seem rather odd. I would steer clear of these methods and stick to [Rx.NET](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET) if you want to use observables. (Rx is usable from F#).

Comment: I think maybe you've misunderstood the question.  The OP is referring to the `Control.Observable` F# module, not `IObservable` or Rx.NET.  The answer was well-explained, just aimed at the wrong thing, IMO.

Comment: (-1) I don't agree with the suggestion to stay clear of those methods... Although the labelling (possibly) isn't the clearest, they do have a useful purpose and frequently come up in various reading material covering observables in the context of F#. Furthermore, this doesn't get straight to the answer.